# Heroku not recognize gradle - Could not find a pom.xml file

Tags: gradle, heroku, gradle-kotlin-dsl

```
-----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/java.tgz
       Could not find a pom.xml file! Please check that it exists and is committed to Git.
       More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
 !     Push failed
```

This is seen in Heroku's web app
[image]

This is my repo: https://github.com/ericntd/spring-boot-heroku-demo

I already have `"image": "heroku/gradle"` in [app.json](https://github.com/ericntd/spring-boot-heroku-demo/blob/master/app.json)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The buildpack information can be found under `Settings` tab, the `Framework` section. (should be `heroku/gradle`).
Besure to remove heroku/java build pack if it's there (auto-detected and added by Heroku)
[image]

Alternative is to use the Heroku CLI and set the build pack desired (gradle)

Comment: I already have `"image": "heroku/gradle"` in my app.json. Why isn't that enough?